# Error: Target container is not a DOM element BASIC REACTJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React, and I was watching a tutorial in YT (https://youtu.be/7MmncixTZOo), the thing is that I'm just trying to print a text in my main file but doesn't work (the screen remains blank).

This is my `package.json` (to check versions, I think React syntax is updated, can be?)

[image]

I just deleted all the files in the "src" folder and created these two ("index.js" and "App.js").

`index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelectorAll('#root'));
```

`App.js`

```
import React from 'react';

const App = () => {
    return <div>App</div>
};

export default App;
```

I get this error:

(I know that the error gives it because there is not created the element ID "root", but if I believe it, my screen is blank and it doesn't print the text "App").

[image]

Can someone lend me a hand?
Thanks a lot of!!!

Cheers.

EDIT: This is my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: does your index.html have a div with id=root?

Comment: please show your index.html structure

Comment: EDIT: Oh, okay ... In index.html, sorry, yes, I update my question :)

Comment: well you need the <div id='root'/> , can you also show me the message in console? also use ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Inside your `index.html file` in your `public folder` you should have a code like this `<div id='root'></div>` where `root` targets your unique `div` element.
2. And in your `index.js file` you should not call a collection with `document.querySelectorAll('#root')` because it returns a collection even if only one occurence matches the `selector`.

Use instead `document.querySelector('#root')` to target the first `selector` that is found.

Technically speaking you can event change the `id property` name into `mammy` inside your `index.html file` like this `<div id='mammy'></div>`.As it `mammy` in your `index.js` it will be `document.querySelector('#mammy')`.It just to help you understand how things really work

I hope that it helped

Comment: Great and clear answer! And to add to that I think you might need to add paranthesis to your return statement in the App component => return (<div>App</div>).

Comment: Thank you!! Now I recieve ```Line 5:35:  'props' is not defined  no-undef```, but I'll investigate ...

Answer (score 1):

You have used

```
document.querySelectorAll
```

that will return a collection of elements not an element.

You need to use:

```
document.getElementById('root')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot of man! This is another solution! :)